# Hardware Accelerated Decoding with OpenCV and Python on Windows (MSMT / IntelMFX / FFMPEG / any backend)

Tags: python, opencv, decoding, hardware-acceleration

I can't get Hardware Accelerated Decoding working with OpenCV on Windows 10.

Any tips? I already compiled and tried all the backends in the lastest OpenCV 4.1.0 for Windows.

I had most faith with the MSMF decoding since it came up with DXVA support.
(MSMF = Microsoft Media Foundation w/ DXVA)

Here is the BuildInformation of OpenCV.

```
getBuildInformation()
{
    Video I/O:
        DC1394:                      NO
        FFMPEG:                      YES (prebuilt binaries)
          avcodec:                   YES (58.35.100)
          avformat:                  YES (58.20.100)
          avutil:                    YES (56.22.100)
          swscale:                   YES (5.3.100)
          avresample:                YES (4.0.0)
        GStreamer:                   YES (1.16.0)
        DirectShow:                  YES
        Media Foundation:            YES
          DXVA:                      YES
        Intel Media SDK:             YES (.../x64/libmfx_vs2015.lib)
}
```

Here are my input video test results.

```
Results()
{
    Intel_MFX   
        [12.0x]     Frame: 12279/0      Speed: 224fps
        Elapsed:    58.081 s  <-- (Result Maxed CPU so it wasnt HWacclerated Decoding)

    FFMPEG  
        [9.4x]      Frame: 12400/12451  Speed: 170fps
        Elapsed:    74.809 s         <-- (Software Decoded, not HWacclerated)


    GSTREAMER
        [1.0x]      Frame: 1382/-1      Speed: 18fps
        Elapsed:    Realtime Video Playback

    MSMT
        ERROR OPENING WITH BACKEND
        Elapsed:    0.172 s

    DSHOW
        ERROR OPENING WITH BACKEND
        Elapsed:    0.002 s
}
```

Here is how I am reading the input file in Python

```
{
video=cv2.VideoCapture('input_video.264', cv2.CAP_INTEL_MFX )
video=cv2.VideoCapture('input_video.264', cv2.CAP_FFMPEG )
video=cv2.VideoCapture('input_video.264', cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER )
video=cv2.VideoCapture('input_video.264', cv2.CAP_MSMF )
video=cv2.VideoCapture('input_video.264', cv2.CAP_DSHOW )
}
```

Is there any easier (HW Accelerated) way to get frames from a video file into OpenCV? I need to parse every 18th frame (1 FPS parsed) for motion activity of security footage. The faster the better!!

Using DXVA Checker, I should be able to achieve 800fps/~40x realtime playback speed with Intel_CPU HW acclerated decoding. (I also have an AMD gpu but its HW accelerated decoding speed SLOW @ 100fps/~5x realtime playback)

Is there an alternative FFMPEG binary I can compile that forces HW Decoding?  I know FFMPEG has support for HW accleration!